# Measuring received video frame rate of rtsp video stream using gscam in ROS

Tags: gstreamer, ros, rtsp

In my Ubuntu 18.04, I am receiving video from an IP camera and transmitting the video to a rtsp server using gscam in ROS melodic. Here is the code for the gscam nodelet in the launch file:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
name="nodelet_manager" args="manager"
output="screen"/>

<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
name="$(arg cam_name)"
args="load gscam/GSCamNodelet nodelet_manager"
output="screen">

<param name="camera_name"          value="$(arg cam_name)"/>
<param name="camera_info_url"      value="$(arg camera_info_url)"/>
<param name="frame_id"             value="$(arg cam_name)"/>
<param name="sync_sink"            value="true" />
<param name="use_gst_timestamps"   value="true" />
<param name="gst_clock_type"       value="0" />    <!-- GST_CLOCK_TYPE_REALTIME -->
<param name="reopen_on_eof"        value="true" />

<!-- choose appropriate gstreamer pipeline -->
<param name="gscam_config"
value="gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=$(arg rtsp_stream) latency=$(arg latency) ! decodebin 
! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB" />

<remap from="camera/image_raw" to="$(arg cam_name)/image_raw" />
</node>
```

Now, I would like to measure the received and dropped frame rate from the camera and from my research I have found that there is a gstreamer element `fpsdisplay` for this purpose.

If I try this launch operation from console :`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.17.168:553/stream latency=400 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink`, then it displays the frame rate on a pooped up window but if I want to use fpsdisplay in the pipeline in the above gscam nodelet in the launch file like this:

```
<param name="gscam_config"
value="gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=$(arg rtsp_stream) latency=$(arg latency) ! fpsdisplaysink ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! 
video/x-raw,format=RGB" />
```

then it does not work, no topics are published.

Through the documentations, I could not understand how to combine `fpsdisplaysink` in the `gscam` pipeline. 
How then this element has to be combined with the pipeline?

Or, if it is not clearly possible to get the received frame rate through `fpsdisplaysink` then how it can be done?

My main goal is not to show the fps on the screen but to get those values and then publish them as a ROS topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_hz solves your problem already?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but by using `rostopic hz` I can only get the rate of publishing and be sure that if any topics are published or not. However, it doesn't give me the fps. I am also not sure that, in gscam how the fpsdisplay should be combined. Anyway, now I am trying to calculat the fps from ROS message header information.